# Change in synchronised thread execution order

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I am executing a [java-synchronisation example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_thread_synchronization.htm):

**Thread call code:**

```
Caller ob1 = new Caller(target, "Hello");
Caller ob2 = new Caller(target, "Synchronized");
Caller ob3 = new Caller(target, "World");
```

**Output:**

```
[Hello]
[World]
[Synchronized]
```

Why does "Synchronized" gets printed last, though it's called in 2nd?

Comment: Consider including an explanation of the code being tested here, rather than forcing readers to study the linked code, which could go away at any point in time.

Comment: I tried to bring the code in the reference thread, but StackOverflow do not allow me to save since it considers code explanation is very less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no guarantee in the order of execution. It is the discretion of the JVM.

Invoking the start() method of a Thread instance doesn't guarantee that it will run after the method call right away.